# Javascript: getElementByID won't work on Aweber form

Tags: javascript

Now that Aweber have added the decorative code to their signup forms, it's difficult for the newbies to pull out the field data to load into a second script. So I devised a little form that takes the "raw HTML" and outputs the field name / value. So far, so good.

```
<script language="javascript">
var o,a;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
    a = c[i].value;
    o+='<tr><td>'+c[i].name+'</td>';
    if (a !='') {
        o+='< d>'+c[i].value+'</td></tr>';
    } else { 
        o+='<td>-</td></tr>';
    }
}
document.write('<hr><table width="500px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1"  align="center">'+o+'</table>');
</script>
```

Now the problem is the line below:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="redirect_2346...46e29de3d26"/>
```

I thought I would be able to use the above code, but use `getElementById()` instead of `getElementByTagName()` to find the value at the end of the line, but all this creates is a null entry, and I can't figure out the reason.

+++

Been trying pattern match this afternnon, and found something interesting.

I loaded it into a variable (t) using innerHTML, and then tried a alert.
The original line is (say):

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="7...36681" />
```

which in the alert becomes ...

```
<input name="meta_web_form_id" value="7...36681" type="hidden">` ie "hidden moves to end. Weird??
```

I then tried - with obvious syntax errors -

```
var x=t.match(/id=\"[0-9a-z]\"/);
var x=t.match(/id=\"+[0-9a-z]+\"/);
var x=t.match(/id=\".[0-9a-z].\"/);
```

to attempt to read from "id=" through to the " at end of long number(which changes its letter/number combination)

I even tried indexOf('id=') which finds the START of the number ... but I can't find a way to work forward from that point to reach the next (")

+++++

I have now managed to 'fiddle' a work around. I don't think it's fair to Stackoverflow web hosts to post the *entire* Aweber form here as it's 7.5K for a basic two field signup form (!!) thanks to all their CSS tables to 'beautify' the form. So I've taken the part that "innerHTML" sees, and put that below:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="7866...681" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="lb-magic" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="redirect_2346818daffbe9b...df846e29de3d26" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="basic_magic" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-786636681" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-786636681"  class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-53468419">Name: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap">
<input id="awf_field-53468419" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" />
</div>
<div class="af-clear"></div></div>
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-53468420">Email: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-53468420" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-53468421">passcode</label>
<div class="af-textWrap">
<input type="text" id="awf_field-53468421" class="text" name="custom passcode" value=''  tabindex="502" /></div>
<div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-53468422">option</label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-53468422" class="text" name="custom option" value=''  tabindex="503" /></div>
<div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="504" />
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=7BxsbMxsbByM" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
(function() {
    var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
    if (!IE) { return; }
    if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
        if (document.getElementById("af-form-786636681")) {
            document.getElementById("af-form-786636681").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
        }
        if (document.getElementById("af-body-786636681")) {
            document.getElementById("af-body-786636681").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
        }
        if (document.getElementById("af-header-786636681")) {
            document.getElementById("af-header-786636681").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
        }
        if (document.getElementById("af-footer-786636681")) {
            document.getElementById("af-footer-786636681").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
        }
    }
})();
-->
</script>
```

And this is my solution to find the form variables

```
<!-- Aweber Decoder by Chris Brown (http://www.cristofayre.com) -->

<!-- Place RAW HTML below this comment-->
<!-- Place RAW HTML above this comment-->

<script language="javascript">
var o,a,st,t,x;
t=document.body.innerHTML;   // put innerHTML into var t
st=t.indexOf('id=');         // find the start of redirect as 'id='
x=t.substr(st,t.length);     // cut off start ot t at this point, and move into x
x=x.replace(/id="/,'');      // remove the 'id="' at start of string
st=x.indexOf('"');           // find the next '"' in string
t=x.substr(0,st);            // cut x from 0 to index found above

var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); // finds all the <input tags
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {            // loop through all inputs
a=c[i].value;                                   // find the value of that input
o+='<tr><td>'+c[i].name+'</td>';                // write the name of that input to table cell
if(c[i].name == 'redirect'){                    // if input name is 'redirect'
o+='<td>'+t+'</td></tr>';                       // add var t to cell instead
continue;                                       // jump to next loop
}
if (a !=''){                                    // if the input value is not empty ...
o+='<td>'+c[i].value+'</td></tr>';              // put the value in table cell and end row
}
else{                                           // but if  the value is empty
o+='<td>-</td></tr>';                           // put a '-' in the table cell
}
}
document.write('<hr><table width="500px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">'+o+'</table>');                     // write out the table and cell data
</script>
```

It might be 'crude' in programming terms, but I prefer to work "logically" so I can see what's happening at each stage rather than use cyptic code shorthand ... as my inability to master "match" above proves!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried or a link to the page in question. You should definitely be able to use getElementById().

Comment: Since "id" is the only one on page, I used var x=getElementById('id') alert(x); which comes back blank

Comment: Just looking again, there are six div / text id's I hadn't seen before. Perhaps I DO need to have a for/next loop to read them all

Comment: make sure the id is not duplicated ie, there is no multiple elements with same id

Comment: Its really not clear what your problem is. Ideally you should post your code that is attempting to use getElementById and the line you are attempting to select. It isn't clear from your question if there is a technical issue or if you are just not clear on how to use the method in question.

Comment: I've managed to get a work around as you'll see above. Don't think it's fair to post the whole Aweber code as it's 7.5K for a simple signup form thanks to all their extra classes / CSS!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo: getElementByTagName() should be `getElementsByTagName()` (plural) and it returns an array.